# Covering a Square Floor with Square Rugs

Tags: geometry, tiling

You are given a finite collection of axis-aligned square rugs. (You do not choose the collection of rugs that you receive and the rugs are not necessarily all the same size.) Your objective is to move the rugs, without rotating them, to completely cover an axis-aligned square floor. The rugs are allowed to overlap.

Can you cover the entire floor if the total area of the rugs is three times the area of the floor?

---

I made this problem up myself and I have not been able to prove it or find a counterexample. My work so far:

---

Let the table have area 1.

Let $N$ be the number of rugs. If $N \in {1,2,3}$ then the answer is trivial. So assume $N \geq 4$.

Let $R_i$ be the $i$-th rug.

Let $r_i$ be the area of the $i$-th rug where $r_i \geq r_{i+1}$ for each $i$. Assume for all $i$, $r_i < 1.$

---

Let $N = 4$. If each rug has area greater than $\frac{1}{4}$. Then we can divide the floor into quarters and cover each quarter with a rug. So we assume otherwise and so $r_4 < \frac{1}{4}$.

Then $\frac{r_1 + r_2 + r_3}{3} > \frac{11}{12}$. Therefore $r_1 > \frac{11}{12}$.

Suppose $r_1 \approx 1$ and $r_2 = r_3$. We find $r_2 > \frac{7}{8}$.

Suppose $r_1 = r_2 \approx 1$. We find $r_3 > \frac{3}{4}$.

Place $R_1$ and $R_2$ in opposite corners. This will leave two uncovered rectangles with side lengths $1 - \sqrt{r_1}$ and $1 - \sqrt{r_2}$.

Place $R_3$ in one of the open corners.

Then we need that $r_4 \geq \left(1 - \sqrt{r_2}\right)^2$ to cover the floor.

Now let $r_1$ and $r_3$ be at their maximums. So that $r_2 + r_4$ is as small as possible.

Let $r_1 \approx 1$. Let $x = r_2 = r_3$ then $r_4 = 3 - (1 + x + x) = 2 - 2x$.

Then using the previous inequality, we need that $2 - 2x > \left(1 - \sqrt{x}\right)^2$. This inequality is true for $0 \leq x < 1$.

Therefore it is always possible to cover the floor for $N = 4$.

---

Generalizing, we can assume for $N \geq m^2$, that there are only $m^2 - 1$ rugs with area greater than $\frac{1}{m^2}$.

So that $r_{m^2} < \frac{1}{m^2}$.

$r_1 > \frac{3 - \frac{N - m^2+1}{m^2}}{m^2-1}$

$r_2 > \frac{2 - \frac{N - m^2+1}{m^2}}{m^2-2}$

$r_3 > \frac{1 - \frac{N - m^2+1}{m^2}}{m^2-3}$

---

I have more to do.

Comment: MSE is not a problem-solving service. You need to tell us something about your thoughts on the problem. I didn't vote to close your question, but this is why someone voted to close it.

Comment: I made this problem up. It's harder than it looks. I can't prove it or find a counter-example. If you need to close it, then go ahead.

Comment: I don't want to close it - it looks interesting. If you'd like some help show us some of your thoughts on it, e.g., some special case where it's true, and we'll take it from there.

Comment: Tip: use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your equations look nicer

Comment: @BassetHoundVideo: *"I made this problem up. It's harder than it looks. I can't prove it or find a counter-example."* This kind of context belongs in the body of the question —comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden— so that the reader has warning about taking on a problem that could turn into a research project. :)

Comment: @RobArthan. The question was posted here instead: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124903/covering-a-square-floor-with-square-rugs

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof:

The floor is assumed to be the unit square. Denote the lengths of the sides of the square rugs by $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. Then $a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2 = 3$ and we may further assume that $1\geq a_1\geq\ldots\geq a_n$.

Now, we subdivide this ordered sequence of squares into smaller sequences of squares such that the sum of the sides of the squares in each sequence is just larger than 1. Formally, this may be accomplished by choosing indexes $0=i_0<i_1<\ldots<i_k\leq n$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{i_1} a_i \geq 1, \sum_{i=1}^{i_1-1} a_i <1,$$
$$\sum_{i=i_1+1}^{i_2} a_i \geq 1, \sum_{i=i_1+1}^{i_2-1} a_i <1,$$
and so on until
$$\sum_{i=i_k+1}^n a_i <1.$$

Each of these sequences $a_{i_{j-1}+1},\ldots,a_{i_j}$ for $j=1,\ldots,k$ covers a rectangle of width at least 1 and height $a_{i_j}$. Thus, we have to prove that
$$ a_{i_1}+\ldots+a_{i_k}\geq 1.$$
(Just place these rectangles below each other into the unit square.)

But we know that
$$3=\sum_{i=1}^{i_1-1}a_i^2 + a_{i_1}^2 + \sum_{i=i_1+1}^{i_2-1}a_i^2 + a_{i_2}^2 + \sum_{i=i_2+1}^{i_3-1}a_i^2 + \ldots + a_{i_k}^2 + \sum_{i=i_k+1}^n a_i^2.$$
Here, each term with a summation sign corresponds to a sequence of squares which can be placed in a rectangle of length at most 1 (as $\sum_{i_{j-1}+1}^{i_j-1} a_i < 1$ by the choice of the $i_j$) and width at most $a_{i_{j-1}}$ (by the monotonic order of the $a_i$). Thus, we find
$$ 3 \leq 1 + a_{i_1}^2 + a_{i_1} + a_{i_2}^2 + a_{i_2} + \ldots + a_{i_k}^2 + a_{i_k}.$$
(Here, each summand corresponds to exactly one summand from the previous equation.)

As all sides are smaller than one, it holds that $a_{i_j}^2\leq a_{i_j}$ and therefore
$$3\leq 1 + 2(a_{i_1}+\ldots+a_{i_k})$$
which proves the desired inequality.

Comment: Why is  $\sum^{i_1-1}_{i=1} a_i^2\leq a_{i_1}+1$. It’s not clear how you got that inequality out from the prior ones.

Comment: @Eric: This sum is less than $1$ as all $a_i$ are at most $1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{i_1-1}a_i <1$ by the choice of $i_1$.  This gives an upper bound for the first summand. (Picture the squares sitting in a row next to each other.) The second summand ($a_{i_1}^2$) is kept and the third term has an upper bound again: $\sum_{i=i_1+1}^{i_2-1}a_i < 1$ by the choice of $i_2$ and each $a_i, i=i_j+1,\ldots,i_2-1$ is at most $a_{j_1}$, thus the area of these squares is less than $1\cdot a_{i_1}=a_{i_1}$. And other terms follow in the same manner. - I edited the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: Nice. So you provide a way of covering as well. You do not say explicitly, although it's deduced, a_0=1

Comment: Suppose $n = 4$ and $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) = \left(\frac{\sqrt{34}}{6}, \frac{\sqrt{33}}{6}, \frac{\sqrt{33}}{6}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\right)$?  How does your proof work for this case?

Comment: Sorry to chime in, but I don't see an issue with your case. $i_1=2$ and $i_2=4$ works OK I think.

Answer (score -1):

Let $a$ = area of the floor.

Let $r(n)$ = equal of each rug

$\epsilon$  = an inifinitesimally small amount.

As a general rule  the larger a rug the more inefficiently it must be used while the smaller a rug the more efficient it gets. (only exception to this is one rug covering the entire floor will be perfectly efficient of course)

For $N=4$, even if $r(1,2,3)$ are each equal to $a-\epsilon$ which is the most inefficient setup possible, the fourth rug will still cover the last remaining corner as the total exposed area is only $\epsilon^2$.

For higher values of $N$ it only gets more and more efficient as the maximum amount of wasted space will always be  to have  $r(1,2,3)$  each equal to $a-\epsilon$

The closest we ever get to needing the full $3a$ area of the rugs is actually for $N=3$

Comment: You do not get to choose the collection of rugs that you receive. You could receive any collection as long as the total area is less than 3.  You did not understand the question. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @BassetHoundVideo He is not really choosing the rugs. This answer is trying to find the worst possible case by seeing which rug sizes would make the problem hardest to solve, and then show that they can then still cover the square, thereby proving it can always be covered. Unfortunately it is currently not rigorous enough to be a proof, but it is certainly a reasonable initial attempt.